# How to get search bar background transparant?(see image)

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I am using a searchcontroller in my view, but I can not get rid of the annoying background of the searchbar.

The code I am using:

```
import UIKit

class systemTable: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate , UISearchResultsUpdating{

@IBOutlet var systemTable: UITableView!
var searchController = UISearchController()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.searchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self
        controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        controller.searchBar.translucent = true
        controller.searchBar.alpha = 1

        controller.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        controller.searchBar.layer.opacity = 1
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
        return controller
    })()


}
```

Image:
[image]

To be clear: I want to get rid of the background which is colored gray in the image above.

Any help is appreciated

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@[image]
EDIT
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
New image(when  trying scrolling down):

Comment: Try this controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
controller.searchBar.backgroundImage=  UIImage()

Comment: Works perfect! And when I slide down I still see gray coming up from the top, how do I get rid of that? @ChandanPrajapati

Comment: which iOS version you r using?

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati 8.0

Comment: replace `controller.searchBar.backgroundImage= UIImage()` with 

`controller.searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)
    searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = UIImage()`

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati not worked, see the new image I added in my edit, I am talking about the gray part

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Its working fine for me, but I am sure you r close to solution. just try it somewhere u r missing.

Here is my code

```
 searchController.searchBar.translucent = true
    searchController.searchBar.alpha = 1
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor. clearColor()
```

Comment: Great solution! In My case I needed light gray text field on white background. In addition to your solution I've added:                                      if let txfSearchField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as? UITextField {
            txfSearchField.borderStyle = .none
            txfSearchField.backgroundColor = colorSBar
            txfSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            txfSearchField.clipsToBounds = true
        }

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the grey Background you're seeing there is the Background color of your UITableView and not the SearchBar / SearchController

Answer (score 0):

try to change the Bar Tint color
that worked for me.